# Based on JEE specs, can a SAR have class visibility of classes in a sibiling WAR?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

I have an EAR file being deployed in Wildfly 10, which includes both a SAR and a WAR.  The SAR has a dependency on a class that is located in the WAR.  From my understanding of the JEE specs, the SAR's classloader should not have any access or visibility on the WAR's classes.  Consequently, WF fails.

However, when reading the [WF Classloader docs](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Class+Loading+in+WildFly), it indicates that there are ways to make classes modules available/visible to other modules within the EAR.

Consequently, I am able to hack around to use the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file to make the WAR module visible to the SAR.  But isn't that breaking the JEE spec?

Comment: Seeing test case about sar classloader you can separate classes present in the .war deployment  in a jar file, and add dependencies like this: https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/master/testsuite/integration/basic/src/test/java/org/jboss/as/test/integration/sar/context/classloader/jboss-deployment-structure.xml, https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/master/testsuite/integration/basic/src/test/java/org/jboss/as/test/integration/sar/context/classloader/MBeanTCCLTestCase.java

Comment: @FedericoSierra That's precisely my thought as well; to make it a separate jar in the EAR/lib folder.  But in doing so, I'm exposing it to every archive in my ear.  Otherwise, put it in a xyz folder and explicitly reference it in the deployment descriptor.  But then that becomes a JBoss specific EAR structure.  But in either case, I'm trying to understand why JBoss even provides a mechanism to circumvent JEE standards and allow my SAR to point to the war as a module for the classloader.